# Can't seem to get rid of OpenSUSE installer from boot menu

Tags: multi-boot, opensuse

So every time I turn this computer on I get presented with two options, Windows 7 and OpenSUSE Installer (local). I need to get rid of the OpenSUSE installer but the usual advice doesn't seem to work.

Firstly I went to remove the partition but then realised there was no other partition, just one volume (Windows (C:)). So I looked around and found an MASM file, an MBR file, and something called OpenSUSE.hitme in My Computer on Windows. I tried getting rid of them, and then loading from the Windows recovery disk and doing bootrec /fixmbr and /fixboot.

But OpenSUSE installer still there as an option :/
How do I get rid of it because there doesn't seem to be any trace of OpenSUSE on the computer left other than on the boot menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try MSCONFIG: run -> msconfig
If that wount help then you could try BCDedit.

At last it could be a GRUB loader, which wasn't properly removed and overright with ms one.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue.
OpenSUSE installer added boot option in boot.ini. You need to delete this option from C:/boot.ini.
In my case I deleted entire file boot.ini because it was created by openSUSE installer and contained only this boot option.

Comment: In any specific way, or will random stuff work?

Comment: Note to others reading: I would strongly suggest NOT deleting C:\boot.ini and also NOT editing it unless you KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING!